# Creating non-overlapping polygons from grouped points

Tags: r, mapping, polygon, r-sp

I have location data for a bunch of towns. I can group them to "territories" based on proximity and some value. How can I create Spatial Polygons Dataframe that capture groups of towns without overlapping, i.e. there are borders/lines between groups?

```
library(ggplot2)
x = rnorm(100)
y = rnorm(100)

x.terr<-as.factor((x<=-1.5)+(x<=-0)+(x<=1.5)+(x<Inf))
y.terr<-as.factor((y<=-1.5)+(y<=-0)+(y<=1.5)+(y<Inf))
terr<-unclass(x.terr)+unclass(y.terr)


Dat = data.frame(x,y,terr)
ggplot(data=Dat)+geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y,color=as.factor(terr)))+
  labs(color="Territory")
```

Desired Output:
[image]